# Obtener un campo mediante Xpath

Tags: html, xpath, selectores-css

Hola tengo este sitio: https://jcmagazine.com/adidas-originals-presenta-la-nueva-coleccion-home-of-classics/ que quiero obtener la fecha de publicación y este dato se encuentra dentro de un script en formato json, la cual pude recuperar todo el contenido del script con este xpath: `//*[@id="the-post"]/script/text()`, y lo hago con una extensión de chrome, se llama: [ScrapeMate Beta](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scrapemate-beta/daiomapeacamgnofkkmiaollhidcndld) y me recupera todo el contenido del script, pero solo quisiera recuperar el valor de: `dateCreated` que seria: `2019-10-13T20:57:43-05:00`, como lo puedo hacer?.

**NOTA:** Solo empleando Xpath o selector.
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo hice de esta forma: `substring(substring-after(//article[contains(@id, 'the-post')]/script/text(), 'dateCreated'),4, 25 )` y el resultado lo puedo visualizar con herramienta llamado: Xpath Helper